# Python 2.7: Matching a subtitle events in VTT subtitles using a regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, webvtt

I'm writing a python script to parse VTT subtitle files.
I am using a regular expression to match and extract specific elements:

- 'in timecode'
- 'out timecode'
- 'other info' (mostly alignment information, like align:middle or line:-1)
- subtitle content (the actual text)

I am using Python's 're' module from the standard library, and I am looking for a regular expression that will match all (5) of the below 'subtitle events':

```
WEBVTT

00:00:00.440 --> 00:00:02.320 align:middle line:-1
Hi.

00:00:03.440 --> 00:00:07.520 align:middle line:-1
This subtitle has one line.

00:00:09.240 --> 00:00:11.080 align:middle line:-2
This subtitle has
two lines.

00:00:15.240 --> 00:00:23.960 align:middle line:-4
Now...
Let's try
four...
lines...

00:00:24.080 --> 00:00:27.080 align:middle
```

PS: Note that stackoverflow doesn't allow me to add an empty line at the end of the code block. Normally the last 'empty' line will exist because a line break (`\r\n` or `\n`). After: `00:00:24.080 --> 00:00:27.080 align:middle`

Below is my code. My problem is that I can't figure out a regular expression that will match **all** of the 'subtitle events' (including the one with an empty line as 'subtitle content').

```
import re
import io

webvttFileObject = io.open("C:\Users\john.doe\Documents\subtitle_sample.vtt", 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') # opens WebVTT file forcing UTF-8 encoding
textBuffer = webvttFileObject.read()

regex = re.compile(r"""(^[0-9]{2}[:][0-9]{2}[:][0-9]{2}[.,][0-9]{3})   # match TC-IN in group1
                         [ ]-->[ ]                                     # VTT/SRT style TC-IN--TC-OUT separator
                         ([0-9]{2}[:][0-9]{2}[:][0-9]{2}[.,][0-9]{3})  # match TC-OUT n group2
                         (.*)?\n                                       # additional VTT info (like) alignment
                         (^.+\n)+\n?                                   # subtitle_content """, re.MULTILINE|re.VERBOSE)

subtitle_match_count = 0
for match in regex.finditer(textBuffer):
    subtitle_match_count += 1
    group1, group2, group3, group4 = match.groups()
    tc_in = group1.strip()
    tc_out = group2.strip()
    vtt_extra_info = group3
    subtitle_content = group4
    print "*** subtitle match count: %d ***" % subtitle_match_count
    print "TIMECODE IN".ljust(20), tc_in
    print "TIMECODE OUT".ljust(20), tc_out
    print "ALIGN".ljust(20), vtt_extra_info.strip()
    print "SUBTITLE CONTENT".ljust(20), subtitle_content
    print
```

I've tried several variations of the regex in the code. All without success. What is also very strange to me is that if I put regex groups in a variable and print them, like I'm doing with this code, I only get the last line as `SUBTITLE CONTENT`. But I must be doing something wrong (right?). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/jBVyPT, the last two lines of your pattern can be turned into `(.*)\r?\n([\s\S]*?)\s*(?:(?:\r?\n){2}|\Z)`

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew this works perfectly. I think you don't need the ...`\r?`... in there. In any case, it worked for me without `\r?` on a Windows machine with a test file with \r\n for the line breaks (Windows style). I prefer the solution offered by @Aran-Fey because (for me) it's more readible. But again this works nicely, so thanks a heap :)

Comment: I just tried to provide a hint that would work without changing modifiers, `[^\n]` will stop working once you have `\r` in the text data. If you only have `\n` endings, then my suggestion will look like [`(.*)\n([\s\S]*?)\s*(?:\n\n|\Z)`](https://regex101.com/r/Tu9oCK/1). [Python demo](https://ideone.com/oeVoJ5). Also, to understand the issue with the last subpattern in your regex, read [**Repeating a Capturing Group vs. Capturing a Repeated Group**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html).

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your regex doesn't match the last subtitle is here:

```
(^.+\n)+\n?
```

The `^.+\n` is looking for a line with 1 or more characters. But the last line in the file is empty, so it doesn't match.

The reason why `subtitle_content` only contains the last line is also there. You're matching each line one by one with `(^.+\n)+`, i.e. the capture group always captures only a single line. With each matched line, the capture group's previous value is discarded, so in the end all you're left with is the last line. If you want to capture *all* lines, you have match them all in one go *inside* of the capture group, for example like this:

```
((?:^.+\n)+)
```

---

In order to make the regex work correctly, I've slightly changed the last two lines:

```
(^[0-9]{2}[:][0-9]{2}[:][0-9]{2}[.,][0-9]{3})
[ ]-->[ ]
([0-9]{2}[:][0-9]{2}[:][0-9]{2}[.,][0-9]{3})
([^\n]*)?\n       # replaced `.*` with `[^\n]*` here because of the S-modifier
(.*?)(?:\n\n|\Z)  # this now captures everything up to 2 consecutive
                  # newlines or the end of the string
```

This regex requires the modifiers `m` (multiline), `s` (single-line) and of course `x` (verbose).

See it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/85JSd3/1).

Comment: Thanks @Aran-Fey this works perfectly. Great explanation.

Comment: This regex is not working for me in the case of multiple content lines: for example `<c.bg_transparent><i>blah blah blah</i></c.bg_transparent> (newline)
<c.bg_transparent><i>like i was saying blah blah</i></c.bg_transparent>` So I prefer  Wiktor Stribiżew solution above in the top comment